# How To Enable SoapClient in PHP 7.3 Ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS Xenial

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, soap, apt-get

Im using PHP 7.3 16.04.7 LTS Xenial, and I cant enable the module SoapClient in my phpinfo().

I already remove the ";" in my php.ini configuration and restart the apache2 to enable the soap module.

The next thing I was recomended doing was to install the php package with

When I run:

> sudo apt install php7.0-soap

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php7.0-soap : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16) but 7.0.33-20+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I check for held packages with:

> dpkg --get-selections | grep hold

I get nothing.

When i run:

> php -v

I get:

```
PHP 7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar 20 2020 13:51:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.16, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.16-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

How can I get out of this broken state where I cant install what I need, and I cant solve held broken packages?

Comment: If you're running PHP 7.3, you should install soap for that version. `php7.0-soap` is for PHP 7.0. Try `sudo apt install php7.3-soap`. On Ubuntu, you usually don't need to manually enable anything in your `php.ini` either when you install PHP extensions.

Comment: I get the following when running ` sudo apt install php7.3-soap` :

`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree`
`Reading state information... Done`
`E: Unable to locate package php7.3-soap`
`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3-soap'`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3-soap'`